# Google finance no longer work?

Tags: google-finance

I used to get stock rate from google finance api by javascript with following url:
http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=BOM:530355

but now it no longer work! I have search on the net but no luck. Any help would be great, Thank!

Answer (score 0):

It appears Google had "officially" desupported this in 2012, but as of this week, has actually shut it down.

Related: [google finance api not working from 6/september/2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090810)'

Related: [google finance json stock quote stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070126)