# Excel VBA - Get Line Number of Specific Word in A String

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get stock prices on Tokyo exchange using VBA. I have searched for quite a number of API but none of them has Tokyo exchange's data, except finance.google.com. But google finance has stopped working and no longer return data in json format so i have to make use of what's left, to extract data from the string returned.

Below is the example of the string returned.

```
EXCHANGE%3DTYO
MARKET_OPEN_MINUTE=540
MARKET_CLOSE_MINUTE=900
INTERVAL=86400
COLUMNS=DATE,CLOSE,HIGH,LOW
DATA_SESSIONS=[MORNING,540,690],[AFTERNOON,750,900]
DATA=
TIMEZONE_OFFSET=540
a1522216800,2313,2324,2240
1,2298,2350,2242
2,2325,2336,2300
5,2252,2333,2246
6,2229,2257,2216 <--
7,2222,2238,2214
8,2262,2267,2220
9,2293,2313,2249
12,2338,2351,2300
13,2373,2392,2351
14,2386,2396,2323
15,2368,2395,2335
16,2391,2398,2375
19,2420,2439,2389
20,2378,2419,2363
21,2411,2428,2389
22,2384,2422,2381
23,2407,2426,2386
26,2437,2438,2389
27,2454,2468,2443
28,2453,2456,2418
29,2437,2422,2443 <<--
```

The URL for your reference 
**http://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?x=TYO&q=9143&i=86400&f=d,c,h,l**

a1522216800 is the timestamp and the first number of the following lines are intervals in days. 1 being 1 day after a1522216800. The timestamp after the alphabet "a" seems to change with days whenever I call that URL.

I use `InStr()` looking for "a" and `Mid()` to extract the timestamp and convert it into date format and add the day interval to the extracted date to get my specific date. 
Here's the problem, for example, I want to get 29 days from the timestamp, indicated by <<--, when I use the same `InStr()` to look for "29," VBA returned string position at <--, as they have the same "29," in that line. How can I get my intended date?

My life would be easier if the response from finance.google.com is in json format. I don't suppose there is a way to convert these string into json are they?

Comment: Try to look for `29,` with the coma?

Comment: [Use a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/11683) in the multiline mode and look for a match in the beginning of a line. Then again, you might want to [stop using it altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46073520/11683).

Comment: I am presuming that there is a new line character at the end of each line and that's why the data is displayed in different lines? If so, use `Split` to capture each line in an array (separating them by the new line character). You can then get the characters until there is a **,** in each item in an array. Use this to check your number

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns  If I search for "29", VBA would return random string position as there are many numbers there and surely there are some "29" hidden somewhere around. That is what I thought at first. So I included the comma thinking very surely it would get me to the last line and here I am with this problem. What's the odds eh

Comment: @Zac The response text returned to VBA is not display as above but in a single line. (Weird it is displayed as above when I pass it into MsgBox but appear as a single line string in local window) So I can't use `Split` as there is no obvious delimiter separating the "29"

Comment: There has to be something that causing it to display the way it is. There might be a hidden character? If you can identify what that character is, you could use that in your `Split`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the below example:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim s
    Dim a

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://finance.google.com/finance/getprices?x=TYO&q=9143&i=86400&f=d,c,h,l", False
        .send
        s = .responseText
    End With
    a = Split(s, vbLf & "29,", 2)
    a = Split(a(1), vbLf, 2)
    a = Split(a(0), ",")

    MsgBox Join(a, vbCrLf)

End Sub
```

Comment: Short and clean. Thanks a lot!